# $\int \frac{-1}{(1-x^2)^{1/2}}\ dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometric-integrals

The answer could be $-\sin^{-1}(x)+C$  or $\cos^{-1}(x)+C$.

I can't decide! as Integration of $1/(1-x^2)^{1/2}$ is $\sin^{-1}(x)+C$

And Derivative of $\cos^{-1}(x)=(1-x^2)^{-1/2}$

Comment: Take a look at [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for information about formatting your question to make it easier to read.

Comment: For `x^???`, use `x^{???}` if '???' is more than one object.

Comment: The derivative of $\arccos x$ is $-(1-x^2)^{-1/2}$.

Answer (score 3):

Are you familiar with the identity $$\arccos x=\frac\pi2-\arcsin x\qquad?\\\ddot\smile$$

Comment: Yess That's why I am confused, how come -Sin^-1(x)=Cos^-1(x)

Comment: They're equal *up to a constant*.

Comment: Hey! Now I know, Is it the Constant C which include pi/2?

Comment: It is not true that $-\arcsin x=\arccos x$. It is true that $$\{C-\arcsin x\,:\, C\in\Bbb R\}=\{C+\arccos x\,:\, C\in\Bbb R\}$$ (of course, not with the same $C$, namely $C'-\arcsin x=C+\arccos x$ with $C'=\frac\pi2+C$)

Comment: omg yes! Tysm!.

Answer (score 0):

> If we put $x=\sin (t) $

with $$-\pi/2\le t\le \pi/2,$$

the integral becomes

$$\int \frac {-\cos (t)dt}{\cos (t)}=-t+C_1 $$
$$=-\arcsin (x)+C_1 $$

> If we put $x=\cos (u) $

with $$0\le u\le \pi,$$

it becomes
$$\int \frac {\sin (u)du}{\sin (u)}=u+C_2 $$
$$=\arccos (x)+C_2. $$

Comment: Thanks mam, thank you very much